# Can we create docker logging plugin in Java? I know we can do it in Go, but can we do it in java?

Tags: docker, plugins, maven-docker-plugin

I am wondering if there is a way to write the docker logging plugin in Java? As per their documentation here https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_logging/, we can create custom docker logging plugin. All I can see is that it has to be in language Go.

Wondering if anyone knows that this can be coded in Java or not? If yes, then a little documentation would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [more generic documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugin_api/) which clarifies that a plugin is a separate process providing a JSON-over-HTTP server.  It looks like the only SDK Docker provides is written in Go, but nothing would stop you from implementing this interface in a different language.

Comment: Thanks David for replying.. Can you point me to any sample code written in Java in case you are aware of?